# ArangoDB: Find all shortest paths

Tags: arangodb, aql

i want to get all shortest paths between 2 vertex.

Example: Give me all shortest path between node A and B should only return the 2 blue paths

[image: example graph]

this is what i have got so far:

```
LET source = (FOR x IN Entity FILTER x.objectID == "organization_1"
    return x)[0]
LET destination = (FOR x IN Entity FILTER x.objectID == "organization_129"
    return x)[0]
FOR node, edge, path IN 1..2 ANY source._id GRAPH "m" 
    FILTER LAST(path.vertices)._id == destination._id
    LIMIT 100
RETURN path
```

Problems:
1. it is very slow (took 18 seconds on a graph with like 70 mio nodes)
2. it finds every path, but i want only all **shortest** path

**UPDATE**
i tried the 2-step query solution from the comments.
the problem is that the second query is also very slow

```
Query string:
 FOR source IN Entity FILTER source.objectID == "organization_1"
 LIMIT 1
 FOR node, edge, path 
   IN 1..@depth ANY source._id 
   GRAPH "m" 
   OPTIONS {uniqueVertices: "path"}
   FILTER node.objectID == "organization_129"
   RETURN path

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType          Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode        1   * ROOT
 11   IndexNode            1     - FOR source IN Entity   /* hash index scan */
  5   LimitNode            1       - LIMIT 0, 1
  6   CalculationNode      1       - LET #6 = source.`_id`   /* attribute expression */   /* collections used: source : Entity */
  7   TraversalNode      346       - FOR node  /* vertex */, path  /* paths */ IN 1..2  /* min..maxPathDepth */ ANY #6 /* startnode */  GRAPH 'm'
  8   CalculationNode    346       - LET #10 = (node.`objectID` == "organization_129")   /* simple expression */
  9   FilterNode         346       - FILTER #10
 10   ReturnNode         346       - RETURN path

Indexes used:
 By   Type   Collection      Unique   Sparse   Selectivity   Fields                       Ranges
 11   hash   Entity          false    false       100.00 %   [ `objectID` ]   (source.`objectID` == "organization_1")
  7   edge   ACTIVITYPARTY   false    false       100.00 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]           base INBOUND
  7   edge   ACTIVITYPARTY   false    false       100.00 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]           base OUTBOUND
  7   edge   ACTIVITY_LINK   false    false       100.00 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]           base INBOUND
  7   edge   ACTIVITY_LINK   false    false       100.00 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]           base OUTBOUND
  7   edge   ENTITY_LINK     false    false        70.38 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]           base INBOUND
  7   edge   ENTITY_LINK     false    false        70.38 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]           base OUTBOUND
  7   edge   RELATION        false    false        20.49 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]           base INBOUND
  7   edge   RELATION        false    false        20.49 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]           base OUTBOUND
  7   edge   SOFT_LINK       false    false       100.00 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]           base INBOUND
  7   edge   SOFT_LINK       false    false       100.00 %   [ `_from`, `_to` ]           base OUTBOUND

Traversals on graphs:
 Id   Depth   Vertex collections                      Edge collections                                                 Options                                   Filter conditions
  7   1..2    Activity, Entity, SOFT_LINK, Property   ACTIVITYPARTY, ENTITY_LINK, SOFT_LINK, RELATION, ACTIVITY_LINK   uniqueVertices: path, uniqueEdges: path   

Optimization rules applied:
 Id   RuleName
  1   move-calculations-up
  2   move-filters-up
  3   move-calculations-up-2
  4   move-filters-up-2
  5   use-indexes
  6   remove-filter-covered-by-index
  7   remove-unnecessary-calculations-2
  8   optimize-traversals
  9   move-calculations-down
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a hash index on field `objectID` in collection `Entity` to avoid the full collection scans, which heavily slows down your performance.

To get all shortest path I would first search for one shortest path with the AQL `SHORTEST_PATH` and return the number of visited vertices. There is also no need of subqueries (like in your query).

```
FOR source IN Entity FILTER source.objectID == "organization_1"
LIMIT 1
FOR destination IN Entity FILTER destination.objectID == "organization_129"
LIMIT 1
RETURN sum(
  FOR v, e
  IN ANY
  SHORTEST_PATH source._id TO destination._id
  GRAPH "m"
  RETURN 1)-1
```

After that I would execute another query with the result from the first query as bind parameter `@depth`, which is used to limit the depth of the traversal.

```
FOR source IN Entity FILTER source.objectID == "organization_1"
LIMIT 1
FOR node, edge, path 
  IN 1..@depth ANY source._id 
  GRAPH "m" 
  OPTIONS {uniqueVertices: "path"}
  FILTER node.objectID == "organization_129"
  RETURN path
```

*Note*: To filter the last vertex in the path you don't have to use `LAST(path.vertices)`, you can simply use `node` because it is already the last vertex (the same applies for `edge`).

Comment: the problem with this solution is: The first query is blazing fast (0.047 s), the second is very slow (17.562 s)

Comment: the problem with searching for every shortest path is, that if you haven't got any filter conditions on the nodes or edges (to exclude a path quickly) and you search the graph in any direction there could be a lot of nodes to visit.

Let's say you have 400 edges per node on average and the shortest path has a deph of 3. Then you have to visit 400^3 = 64,000,000 nodes plus the same amount of edges to get all shortest paths.